# Using a timer thread in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I am doing an application that needs a some kind of a system clock, a clock that counts ticks. I should be able to get the count value and set it.

I have done it using Thread library in the Python language, yet I could not do the same thing with the Timer class in C#. As someone new to .NET, I am not sure how this timer class works. I would love to to be able to implement the same clock using .NET.

Here is my Python code, so you can get an idea of what I'm talking about.

```
class SystemClock(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self , timeUnit , sched):
      self.val = 0

      self.unit = timeUnit
      self.stp= False
      self.sched = sched
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
      while not self.stp:
          self.val +=1
          time.sleep(self.unit)

  def getSystemTime(self):
      return self.val

  def stop(self):
      self.stp = True
```

I appreciate your help;

Comment: Your Python code makes for a *very* poor timer, it quickly falls behind.  At least use Environment.TickCount or DateTime.Now, it doesn't require a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you don't just retrieve a DateTime at the start and, as necessary to have the value, use an `DateTime.Now.Subtract(origDateTime)` and use the TimeSpan result for what you need? Or is this updating something with every tick?

**EDIT**
Also, as with Timers, you set a "Tick" interval, so you don't need to sleep them. Every tick will execute the callback saving you the trouble of using a while...sleep. But bare in bind, while in threading territory, and I can't verify as it's been a while since I've used timers, you may need to lock() the variable you're modifying as it's in a separate thread as nothing is securing that another method isn't altering the same value.

**EDITv3**

Here's version 3 of the edit. You have two classes, both avoiding the use of a timer (which your CPU will thank me later ;-p) `SystemClock` is a typical one-per-second interval rate. `VariableSystemClock` allows you to specify the rate of the increases. I also changed the way you get the value from a property to a method, and even used inheritance. ;-)

SystemClock.cs

```
public class SystemClock
{
    protected DateTime _start;

    public SystemClock()
    {
        this._start = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public virtual Int32 getSystemTime()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(this._start).TotalSeconds));
    }
}
```

VariableSystemClock.cs

```
public class VariableSystemClock : SystemClock
{
    private TimeSpan _interval;

    public VariableSystemClock(TimeSpan interval)
        : base()
    {
        this._interval = interval;
    }

    public override Int32 getSystemTime()
    {
        Double ellapsed = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(this._start).Ticks / this._interval.Ticks;
        return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(ellapsed));
    }
}
```

program.cs (so you can test it in a console application (project->new->console application)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SystemClock oncePerSecond = new SystemClock();
        VariableSystemClock oncePerInterval = new VariableSystemClock(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        Console.WriteLine("Start:");
        Console.WriteLine("  oncePerSecond:   {0}", oncePerSecond.getSystemTime());
        Console.WriteLine("  oncePerInterval: {0}", oncePerInterval.getSystemTime());
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // sleep three seconds
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            // display output
            Console.WriteLine("Interval {0}:", i);
            Console.WriteLine("  oncePerSecond:   {0}", oncePerSecond.getSystemTime());
            Console.WriteLine("  oncePerInterval: {0}", oncePerInterval.getSystemTime());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End:");
        Console.WriteLine("  oncePerSecond:   {0}", oncePerSecond.getSystemTime());
        Console.WriteLine("  oncePerInterval: {0}", oncePerInterval.getSystemTime());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Feel free to play with both the oncePerInterval construct and the Sleep within the for loop.

Comment: No Reason , if there is an alternative way i would be happy if you show me

Comment: And yet another update, hopefully that will give you some insight without the use of threading. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`, as that's *exactly* what it's for.

```
// at the start of your program
Stopwatch SystemClock = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// any time you want to see how much time has elapsed
long ticks = SystemClock.ElapsedTicks;
```

If you really need to be able to set the value, then wrap this in a class that has a `base_time` value (in ticks), and then add the elapsed ticks to your base time to get the time you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Thread Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx5easy.aspx) may be more what you're after.